# Using a script to compare directories with modified file names?

Tags: regex, bash, directory

I want to write a script that compares two directories. 
However, the file names are modified in one of them. 
So directory A contains files like HouseFile.txt, CouchFile.txt, ChairFile.txt
Directory B contains House.txt, Couch.txt, Chair.txt (which should be seen as 'equivalent' to the above)
Both may also contain new, completely different files.

Could someone point me in the right direction here? It's been a while since I've done scripting.

I have tried using `diff`, and I know I need to use some form of `regex`to compare the file names, but I am not sure where to start.

Thank you!

**Added for clarification:**

Of course `diff`, however,  just compares the actual file names. I would like to know how to specify that I regard files names such as, in the example, "HouseFile.txt" and "House.txt" as equivalent in this case

Comment: What did you get after trying `diff`? How far did you get?

Comment: Of course diff just compares the actual file names. I would like to know how to specify that I regard files names such as, in the example, "HouseFile.txt" and "House.txt" as equivalent in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is a possible solution to compare a to b:

`mkdir a b ; touch a/HouseFile.txt a/ChairFile.txt a/CouchFile.txt a/SomeFile.txt b/House.txt b/Chair.txt b/Couch.txt b/Sofa.txt`

`for file in a/*(.); do [[ ! -f b/${${file##*/}:fs@File@} ]] && echo $file ; done`

Outputs: 
`a/SomeFile.txt`

What is not clear to me: Is the difference pattern strictly 'File' or any arbitrary string?

EDIT: The previous was for zsh. Here is one for bash:

```
find a -type f -maxdepth 1 | while read file; do
  check=$(echo $file | sed -r -e 's@(.*)/(.*)@\2@' -e "s@File@@") ;
  [[ ! -f b/${check} ]] && echo $file
done
```

Using parameter expansion instead of `sed`:

```
find a -type f -maxdepth 1 | while read file; do
  check=${file/%File.txt/.txt} #end of file name changed
  check=${check/#*\//} #delete path before the first slash
  [[ ! -f b/${check} ]] && echo $file
done
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get a syntax error 'unexpected ) ' for your answer. Could you please double check it? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. The bash one seems to work. Would be great if you could give a short description of what each part does, specifically the section `do check=$(echo $file | sed -r -e 's@(.*)/(.*)@\2@' -e "s@File@@") ; [[ ! -f b/${check} ]`

Comment: Use `bash`'s parameter expansion instead of `sed`: `check=${file/%File.txt/.txt}`. A bit simpler, and saves a process.

Comment: Could you tell me how? I am not sure how `sed` works in the first place, therefore don't know how to use paramater expansion instead.

Comment: Explanation for the sed version: 's@(.*)/(.*)@\2@' removes everything from the left side up to the last slash. "s@File@@" replaces the string File with an empty string, that is it removes it.

Comment: @chepner your answer returns CouchFile.txt, HouseFile.txt, ... etc instead of just SomeFile.txt as it should. Could you double check it?

Comment: updated answer by @chepner for correctness. thanks for your help